# Настройка PHPstorm и tortoiseHG на Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm, tortoise-svn

Не работает подсветка изменённых строк. После редактирования строки она подсвечивается (как и должно быть), а потом в консоли выводится сообщение:

> Could not execute hg status command : [thg: option --config not recognized]

И выделяется весь файл как изменённый. На винде эта связка работает прекрасно.

Версии: PHPstorm 8, Ubuntu 14.4, tortoise 8.8.2

Comment: PHPStorm работает с меркуриалом из каробки, нужно только установить его sudo apt-get install mercurial. Как установлен и для чего нужен tortoiseHG?